# Spring data find by "_class " value

Tags: mongodb, repository, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

We are using spring data mongo repositories to store/retrieve documents. Following is the Java structure of classes we have got:
Abstract class A -> Concrete Classes B and C
We are writing the documents using save() method. when a document is saved, "_class" variable is saved which stores the classPath.
Now, when we try and query the data, we are getting the documents of both B and C classes. Following is the example:

```
public List<B> findByName (String name);
```

When we call this method, the list (surprisingly) contains the objects of C as well. It may be because B and C have one property which has same name.
My question is, if we want to restrict the result to specific class, is it possible using Mongo repository?
We tried with findBy_Class, findByClass but it threw an exception saying it was not able to find "class" member in "B".

Shouldn't the return type (e.g. List<**B**>) help filtering the objects? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring repository auto casts entities with different class types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965587/spring-repository-auto-casts-entities-with-different-class-types)

Answer (score 1):

On the query object there's a "restrict" method which returns only objects of a given type.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html
I suppose you could do something like that :

```
query.restrict(B.class).findByName(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I am using MongoRepository and not Mongo operation object. So, I will just define the methods in interface and those methods will be transformed into queries as explained in this url: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-lookup-strategies. Don't know whether there is any way to specify the class here.

Comment: I'm very late, but this question is among the top positions in Google when looking for "_class" and MongoRepository. I think that the right solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965587/spring-repository-auto-casts-entities-with-different-class-types
I flagged this question as duplicate to redirect users to the other answer