# Spring repository auto casts entities with different class types

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm using MongoRepository interface to extend my custom repositories for different entities. Now I faced with problem, let's assume an example:
I have 2 entities:

```
@Document(collection = "person")
public class Employee {
    private String position;
}
```

and

```
@Document(collection = "person")
public class Manager {
    private String major;
}
```

repositories for both:

```
@Repository
public interface ManagerRepository extends MongoRepository<Manager, String> {}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String> {}
```

Everything goes well when I saving 2 models:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5541f988d4c603ebac18a147"),
    "_class" : "com.igmtechnology.gravity.core.init.test.Manager",
    "major" : "majority"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5541f988d4c603ebac18a148"),
    "_class" : "com.igmtechnology.gravity.core.init.test.Employee",
    "position" : "developer"
}
```

But when I'm doing findAll() from one of repositories I'm getting 2 objects and one of them spring is automatically casting to another one.
How can avoid this auto casting? Or how can specify which class I need to get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For both of the repositories, you can use the `@Query` annotation to specify a MongoDB JSON query string that will be used instead of query derived from the method's name (you must know that there's a convention for parsing the repository's method names and for building MongoDB queries).

So, by using `@Query`, you can do:

```
@Repository
public interface ManagerRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String>

  @Query(value="{ '_class' : 'com.igmtechnology.gravity.core.init.test.Manager' }")
  List<Person> findAllManagers();

}
```

Behind the scenes, this will generate a query, similar to this one:

```
db.person.findAll({'_class' ; 'com.igmtechnology.gravity.core.init.test.Manager'});
```

However, there's a minor problem with this code. If you change the fully-qualified class name of `Manager`, then the query would not throw a `RuntimeException`, but would return nothing. In this case you can use a wildcard within the `@Query`.

```
@Query(value="{ '_class' : ?0 }")
List<Person> findAllManagers(String className);
```

Then, when you invoke the method, you can just do:

```
managerRepository.findAllManagers(Manager.class.getName());
```

The provided `Manager.class.getName()` will replace the `?0` wildcard and your query will built properly.

Same goes for the `Employee` repository with the difference that you have to provide the fully-qualified class name of `Employee` in the `@Query`'s `value` attribute.

More info:

- [Spring-data MongoDB repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I knew about this kind of solution, but I don't really like it, cause if my entity will change com.igmtechnology.gravity.core.init.test.Manager -> com.solution.test.Manager I will not catch run time error, but always will find empty List.

Comment: Yes, it works fine and this is a good solution! Last question - what should I do if the query will have more criterias such as - 'name'? If I add method like     
@Query("{'_class' : ?0, 'name' : ?1}")
    List<Manager> findAllManagersByName(String className, String name);
it'll be working fine but still have a problem if 'name' will be renamed. Is there similar solution for more criterias?

Comment: No, I don't think wildcards are valid for keys, but only for value placeholders

Comment: @maxi You can use `@TypeAlias`, which will use the given value as a replacement for the entity class name.